# No notification after closing or holding questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, notifications, on-hold

I have been using this site for a year now. I've asked many questions and also answered many times.

Today one of my questions was put on hold by some experienced users. This is fine, but I was not notified of this in the notification panel. Only when I checked in on hold question did I learn that it was put on hold.

Why was there no notification in my inbox after it was put on hold?

Comment: I also think the system should follow up with the people that voted. I often like to know if the question that I voted to close, got closed or not. And I find myself checking back to them periodically