# Duplicate my question by saying this question already answer

Tags: discussion, meta, duplicate-answers

Recently I asked a question on this site and an expert marked my question duplicate, saying.. "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question". But the mentioned duplicate question doesn't have any answer. So how could one say something like this which is complete invalid. Why they did this by giving invalid statements?

Here's my question [No notification after closing or holding questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212098/no-notification-after-closing-or-holding-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Not to be ironic or anything. ;P

Comment: How could u find this duplicate so fast.. Why not me!!